# Inno Setup, slow from cd rom

Tags: installation, windows-installer, inno-setup

I'm using Inno Setup Compiler 5.4.3. to create install app

My app has this structure:

- app.exe
- data

Where data is the folder where I keep all the app related files (jpg images). The app will be distributed from a cd-rom. After creating installation using wizard I got one file witch size is 300Mb.

The problem is that it takes 2-3 minutes for system to open it from a cd. I guess that this is because of the file size. That is too much time without any kind of response from installer.

Is there some simple solution for this situation?
I don't need to compress files and I would be fine if I could make installer structure to look the same as app structure (not to have only one file...). Any kind of solution that will make it perform faster would be good.

Thanks,
Vedran

UPDATE:
Here is how my Files setup looks like:

```
[Files]
Source: "C:\data\palacabencic\bin\PalacaBencic.exe"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion
Source: "{src}C:\data\palacabencic\bin\data\*"; DestDir: "{app}\data"; Flags: external
```

if I try to put {src} and external:

```
Source: "{src}C:\data\palacabencic\bin\data\*"; DestDir: "{app}\data"; Flags: external
```

it doesn't add the data folder in installer folder, it creates only setup file

Comment: You can set [Compression](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=setup_compression) to 'none', but the slowness might be depending on the read speed..

Answer (score 3):

Specify the `external` flag at your [`[Files]`](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/topic_filessection.htm) section records. Note that:

> When the flag external is specified, Source must be the full pathname
>   of an existing file (or wildcard) on the distribution media or the
>   user's system (e.g. "{src}\license.ini").

Something like this should prevent to incude the file into the output setup file:

```
[Files]
Source: "{src}\Image.jpg"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: external
```

Comment: I guess reading a big file from the optical drive would be faster than reading a thousand smaller files, but OP can test of course..

Comment: @Sertac, agree, but in this case is not a good idea to include the files (even when they would be compressed in one file) into the output setup file since the setup file has to be fully read from the medium before it's launched. IMHO the best would be to compress all the image files but keep them separately from the setup file, once the installation process start, extract the files from that archive. I bet there will be some some settings combination for this.

Comment: > *"the setup file has to be fully read from the medium before it's launched"* > I don't think that's correct.

Comment: @Sertac, I meant the setup file has to be extracted in the temp directory before install, thus fully read.

Comment: I've try it like this:

`
[Files]
Source: "C:\data\palacabencic\bin\PalacaBencic.exe"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion
Source: "{src}C:\data\palacabencic\bin\data\*"; DestDir: "{app}\data"; Flags: external
`

but it does'nt copy the "data" folder

Comment: Use only the full path like `C:\data\palacabencic\bin\data*` without the `{src}` constant.

Comment: No result with this setup, it makes only setup file.. Source: "C:\data\palacabencic\bin\data*"; DestDir: "{app}\data"; Flags: external

Comment: Sorry, I'm afraid I don't get your last comment. The `external` flag means just that the files won't be included into the output setup file, but when you go through the wizard and run the installation process, they should be copied from the specified source into the target.

Comment: ok, I think I get it now.. so if flags is "external" than "data" folder will be where it is now, but installer will make a copy of it in DestDir when installing?

Comment: Almost, if you use e.g. `Source: "C:\data*"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: external` then the content of the `C:\data` directory won't be included in the output setup file (won't be compressed into the output `Setup.exe` file) but will be copied from there into the specified `DestDir` when you start the installation process.

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is Explorer trying to find/verify the code signing certificate on the setup executable before launching it. As the file is large, it reads the entire file at least once before it even tries to run it.
This is the same problem as documented in the [Inno KB article](http://www.jrsoftware.org/iskb.php?wrongicon) that causes the icon to not show up.

The solution to this is to use the `external` flag on the data files (as suggested by [TLama](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10968484/588306)), or disk spanning to split the setup into the main setup and the data files.

Answer (score 0):

When you use the `external` flag, you are telling Inno to copy files that are already available uncompressed on the user's system (in your case, on the CD).  And `{src}` specifies a path relative to the setup.exe itself.

```
[Files]
Source: "C:\data\palacabencic\bin\PalacaBencic.exe"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion
Source: "{src}\data\*"; DestDir: "{app}\data"; Flags: external
```

The output of the compile will be only the setup program, but after you have copied this and your data files to your CD then it will copy both to the final installation path when you run the installer.